# Simpler approach to node diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-matrix

I am trying to create a diagram similar to the one below

[image]

However there are some problems with the diagram.

- Can the diagram be simplifed by using 90degree turns?
- Is there a simple way to remove the spacing between the drawn lines?
- Why is there a big black horizontal line to the right?
- Is there another approach to produce a similar image? (I felt my approach was very much bruteforce)

Thanks in advance =)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
               row sep=3em,
               column sep=2em,
               minimum width=2em,
               nodes in empty cells, 
               nodes={anchor=center}]
  {
       & & &        &   & & \neg t & & &  \\
       & & &      q &   & &      r & & &   \\
     T & & &      r &   & &      t & & & T \\
       & & &      t &   & &      p & & &    \\
       & & & \neg r &   & &        & & &  \\};

    \draw (m-3-1) -- (m-3-2) ;

    \draw  (m-2-6) -- (m-2-4) -- (m-2-2) -- (m-4-2) -- (m-4-3);

    \draw (m-4-3) -- (m-3-3) -- (m-3-4) -- (m-3-5) -- (m-4-5);
    \draw (m-4-3)            -- (m-4-4)            -- (m-4-5);
    \draw (m-4-3) -- (m-5-3) -- (m-5-4) -- (m-5-5) -- (m-4-5);

    \draw (m-2-6) -- (m-1-6) -- (m-1-7) -- (m-1-8) -- (m-2-8);
    \draw (m-2-6)            -- (m-2-7)            -- (m-2-8);
    \draw (m-2-6) -- (m-3-6) -- (m-3-7) -- (m-3-8) -- (m-2-8);

    \draw  (m-4-5) -- (m-4-7) -- (m-4-9) -- (m-2-9) -- (m-2-8);
    \draw (m-3-9) -- (m-3-10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you consider using `pstricks`?

Comment: I do not have any suggestions for a solution, as I have never drawn a graph or a tree in TikZ, but this is not a matrix, so you should misuse one for this.

Comment: @Bernard, yes `pstricks` is fine.
@hpekristiansen, I know! That is why  I asked whether there existsted a better method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use less `&` and draw the lines with the help of `++(...)` and `xshift`.

The black vertical rule is probably due to an `Overfull \hbox`, if you're running your actual document in draft mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
        row sep=3em,
        column sep=8em,
        minimum width=2em,
        nodes in empty cells, 
        nodes={anchor=center}]
        {
          &        & \neg t &   \\
          &      q &      r &   \\
        T &      r &      t & T \\
          &      t &      p &   \\
          & \neg r &        &   \\
        };
        \draw (m-3-1.east) -- ++(2em,0) |- (m-2-2) -- (m-2-3);
        \draw (m-3-4.west) -- ++(-2em,0) |- (m-2-3);
        \draw ([xshift=2em]m-3-1.east) |- (m-4-2) -- (m-4-3);
        \draw ([xshift=-2em]m-3-4.west) |- (m-4-3);
        \draw (m-3-2.east) -- ++(2.5em,0) |- (m-5-2);
        \draw (m-5-2.west) -- ++(-2.5em,0) |- (m-3-2);
        \draw (m-1-3.east) -- ++(2.5em,0) |- (m-3-3);
        \draw (m-3-3.west) -- ++(-2.5em,0) |- (m-1-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I only have a small improvement to offer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
               row sep=3em,
               column sep=2em,
               minimum width=2em,
               nodes in empty cells, 
               nodes={anchor=center}]
  {
       & & &        &   & & \neg t & & &  \\
       & & &      q &   & &      r & & &   \\
     T & & &      r &   & &      t & & & T \\
       & & &      t &   & &      p & & &    \\
       & & & \neg r &   & &        & & &  \\};

    \draw (m-3-1) -- (m-3-2.center) ;

    \draw  (m-2-6.center) -- (m-2-4) -- (m-2-2.center) -- (m-4-2.center) -| (m-4-3.center);

    \draw (m-4-2.center) -- (m-4-3.center) -- (m-3-3.center) -- (m-3-4) -- (m-3-5.center) -- (m-4-5.center);
    \draw (m-4-3.center)            -- (m-4-4)            -- (m-4-5.center);
    \draw (m-4-3.center) -- (m-5-3.center) -- (m-5-4) -- (m-5-5.center) -- (m-4-5.center);

    \draw (m-2-6.center) -- (m-1-6.center) -- (m-1-7) -- (m-1-8.center) -- (m-2-8.center);
    \draw (m-2-6.center)            -- (m-2-7)            -- (m-2-8.center);
    \draw (m-2-6.center) -- (m-3-6.center) -- (m-3-7) -- (m-3-8.center) -- (m-2-8.center);

    \draw  (m-4-5.center) -- (m-4-7) -- (m-4-9.center) -- (m-2-9.center) -- (m-2-8.center);
    \draw (m-3-9.center) -- (m-3-10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I replaced the nodes by their centers except for those in 4th, 7th and 10th column. The black bar never appeared.

Answer (score 3):

A `pstricks` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-tree, multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% To compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)

\begin{document}

\[
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 0.6cm}
\begin{psmatrix}[emnode = p, colsep = 0.6cm, rowsep = 0.5cm]
& & & & &[name = nt] ¬ t & \\
& & [name = q] q & & & [name = ra] r & \\
[name = Tb] T & & [name = rb] r & & & [name = ta] t & & [name = Te] T \\
& & [name = tb] t & & & [name = p] p \\
& & [name = nr] ¬ r
\psset{linecolor = LightSteelBlue, linejoin = 1, armB = 0.5cm, angleB = 180, nodesep = 3pt}
%% Upper \branch
{\psset{nodesepB =0pt, armB = 0.7}\ncangle{Tb}{2,2} \ncangle{Tb}{4,2}}
{\psset{nodesepA =0pt}\ncline{2,2}{q}
\ncangle[angleA = 90]{2,5}{nt}\ncangle[angleA = -90]{2,5}{ta}}
\ncline{q}{ra}
{\psset{nodesepB = 0pt}
\ncangle[angleB = 90]{nt}{2,7}\ncangle[angleB = -90]{ta}{2,7}}
\ncangle[angleB = 90]{ra}{Te}
%% Lower branch
{\psset{nodesepA = 0pt}
\ncline{4,2}{tb}\ncangle[angleA = 90]{4,2}{rb}\ncangle[angleA = -90]{4,2}{nr}}
\ncline{tb}{p}
{\psset{nodesepB = 0pt}
\ncangle[angleB = 90]{rb}{4,4}\ncangle[angleB = -90]{nr}{4,4}}
\ncangle[angleB = -90]{p}{Te}
\end{psmatrix}
\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Caramba! I'll have to add another column… It'll be fixed in a moment.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. Actually, I don't look very much TV, and I'm in France. I've seen one of her songs was used in a film  of the French director François Ozon (in the German version of the song).

Comment: @CarLaTeX: B.t.w. do you know if she's from the family of the futurist painter Carlo Carrà?

Comment: I don't know but I don't think so :):):)